# XCode breaks managedObjectModel?

Tags: xcode, core-data

Well, this is embarrassing. Until late last night development was smooth. I had recently upgraded XCode to 4.3.2 (iPhone was complaining). Enjoying implementing and testing a couple of new features;compiling every now and then. When I thought, well, for a final run let's delete the app from the device and walk through the whole process before submitting it to Apple.

Then it happened. Suddenly the app compiles straight into a wall complaining about the managedObjectModel being nil. Since I have not changed any code in regards the core-data, I have come to the conclusion that I have not the slightest clue what the problem is.

Is it possible that the upgrade to XCode broke the CoreData version migration ? What can I do about it ?

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }




    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"userinfo" withExtension:@"momd"];


    NSLog(@"Model URL %@" , modelURL);


    __managedObjectModel =[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL]  ;


    NSLog(@"Model Entities %@" , [__managedObjectModel entities]);


    return __managedObjectModel;


}
```

Here is the output for the above code: As we can see, no managedObjectModel is assigned.
How can this be ? It was working perfectly just the day before.

Model URL file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/[ID Info]/[App Name].app/userinfo.momd/

2012-04-06 07:39:50.375 [App Name][861:707] Model Entities (null)